# laravel migration is not creating the expected columns in the database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, migration, laravel-10

Laravel migrations are not creating the expected columns in the database, and only the default id and timestamps columns are being created, explain reasons for this issue

but it just create id, created_at and updated_at column in database

Comment: After making changes to the migration file, it's important to save the file before running the migration command (php artisan migrate). this was my mistake now i got it

Comment: You should provide at least the migration you are talking about and also the output when executing the migration. It might be that you have already executed it once, so without rolling it back you won't be able to execute it again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.